# What are equivalent parameters of adduser debian command in RHEL6?

Tags: debian, redhat, rhel6

None of this options doesn't exist in RHEL6.

```
/usr/sbin/adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git
```

What is equivalent parameters for disabling account (no locking, it's different) and adding gecos in Red Hat 6 ?

Comment: See the [Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-users-tools.html#s2-users-tools-users-add).

Comment: there's nothing in deployment guide regarding "--disabled-login" option. please don't do offtopic and check your links first

Comment: It helps if you actually read it.

Comment: it's not the same explanation as user above, provided. I mean if you only gonna throw the docs and close the topics, you should leave serverfault now. this community intended to help on guiding over documentation also. and "spoon fiding" is welcome in here in case you don't know.

Comment: This is a site for **professionals**, and as such, we do **not** do spoon feeding. You are expected to read AND UNDERSTAND the product documentation prior to coming here. I'm sorry, but you did _not_ do one or both of those.

Comment: You should read the man page carefully before asking, "asking why, don't asking what"

Comment: nice, then this site is dead for me, because it was all about spoon feeding since I've joined in here. A documentation, a.k.a man pages is biggest problem of unix world, where even developers can't find information in there. I've came from BSD and Debian, I want exact functionality in there regarding default unix tools, if it's not, I'm reading man pages, if no option found in here - I'm coming here, and NO, I won't even intended to open RHEL manuals because there's at least 20 vers of them for same tool which is even more confusing. since when you develop a rules? this community about guiding

Comment: ok we done go here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183829/since-when-spoon-feeding-is-not-allowed

Comment: This site (i.e. ServerFault) has never been about spoonfeeding. A basic unix/linux question would be better asked in Unix/Linux or possibly SuperUser.

Comment: That could've been explained from the beginning. Thank you Jenny.

Comment: It is explained in the [faq] which you did not bother to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Debian `adduser` manpage:

```
   --disabled-login
          Do  not  run passwd to set the password.  The user won't be able
          to use her account until the password is set.
```

By default, when using `useradd`, the account is disabled until you set a password on it for the first time, so simply not giving the user a password will accomplish the same thing as `adduser --disabled-login`.